# How can I get powershell to return the correct exit code when called with the -File argument?

Tags: powershell, exit-code

Powershell is returning a 0 exit code, when an error has occurred, if called with the -File argument. Which means my build is green when it shouldn't be :(

For example:

(in wtf.ps1)

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";   
$null.split()
```

(cmd)

```
powershell -file c:\wtf.ps1  
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\wtf.ps1:3 char:12
+ $null.split <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], ParentConta
   insErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


echo %errorlevel%  
0

powershell c:\wtf.ps1  
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\wtf.ps1:3 char:12
+ $null.split <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (split:String) [], ParentConta
   insErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull


echo %errorlevel%  
1
```

Any ideas?

(I've tried pretty much every idea from the first 2 pages of this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=powershell+file+argument+exit+code already)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the script, use the exit keyword with a number of your choice:

```
exit 34
```

Here's the script I used to test this:

```
## D:\Scripts\Temp\exit.ps1 ##
try{
    $null.split()
}
catch
{
    exit 34
}

exit 2
#############################

# launch powershell from cmd 
C:\> powershell -noprofile -file D:\Scripts\Temp\exit.ps1
C:\>echo %errorlevel%
34
```

Comment: If it's a terminating error, the exit never gets called :( And, even if I try/catch and exit >0, if I call it with -File I lose the exit code.

Comment: Hmm, your example works for me. And yet, my build is still green. I'll see if I can work out what's different.

Answer (score 12):

It is [a known problem](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/750653/powershell-exe-doesn-t-return-correct-exit-codes-when-using-the-file-option). Workarounds are calling the script with -File, using the -Command parameter (and adding ; exit $lastexitcode if you also have your own exit codes) or turning them into exit codes like [Shay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10620837/1242) is showing or the example using trap below. See [here](http://joshua.poehls.me/2012/powershell-script-module-boilerplate/) for more information.

```
trap
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Continue";   
    Write-Error $_
    exit 1
}

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";   
$null.split()
```

Comment: This workaround works well in Jenkins. I simply used the following Windows PowerShell command: PowerShell -File "srcipt.ps1"; exit $lastexitcode;